Jupyter Notebook does not release ports
I have into difficulty with Jupyter Notebooks. I am working on Linux and usually work on my files by opening Terminal in the particular folder or going through "Run Command" option (MX Linux, Debian based distro, file manager is Thunar). And Jupyter nicely opens content of only that particular folder.
However, today I opened notebook on desktop as I was doing some quick calculus and afterwards deleted the files.
Now what happens is that no matter which folder I start Jupyter in, it always opens desktop content only, as if by default.
I am not sure what changed.
Again, I would like to restore the option so that jupyter notebook opens only in the folder where I accessed it through the terminal.
UPDATE:
I have discovered where the problem is. It seems even after the kernel is seemingly shut down in web browser (Firefox), it continues to run in the background on port 8888 (default one). This seems to be to cause of "returning" me to previously opened folder/local instance.
I can resolve it temporarily by jupyter notebook stop which closes all servers, but as I understand, this is supposed to happen automatically after I quit in browser.
